# How to execute "current" query in oracle sql developer worksheet without highlighting or requiring a ; terminator

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently I need to either select the query by highlighting it or have a ; delimiter. Based on my research it seems I need to set sqlterminator false. However in Oracle 11g I get following error:

```
"set SQLTERMINATOR off" is Obsolete.
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a `;`?

Comment: I have used other tools like toad which do not have such requirement. So am bit stuck to that habit.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single query, you do not need to terminate it with a special character (default is semicolon) as the parser will be able to determine the beginning and end of the query. Because whitespace is allowed anywhere within a query, if you have more than one query in your worksheet, there is no way for the parser to distinguish between them without either manually selecting the query you want to run or terminating with the special character.

Semicolons are great and I highly recommend using them to terminate all of your Oracle queries.

Comment: Disagree. Why cant a new line character be used to distinguish multiple queries like toad does?

Comment: All programming languages have line terminator and stubbornly enforce syntax rules. Is that too much to ask? (Newline symbol is a whitespace which is ignored by parser).

Comment: For the same database (oracle) toad allows to use new line character as separator. I am trying to similar behavior from other tool pl sql developer.